# Не работает скрипт js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, почему не работает js. http://jsbin.com/husuzo/1/edit

Вот эта часть кода скрывает все менюшки в шапки:

```
if(window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth<=480){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#header ul').addClass('hide');
        $('#header').append('<div class="leftButton" onclick="toggleMenu()">Меню</div>');
    });
    function toggleMenu(){
        $('#header ul').toggleClass('hide');
        $('#header .leftButton').toggleClass('pressed');
    }
}
```

А вот эта часть кода должна вставлять часть кода с другой страницы, не заменяя её:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadPage();
});
function loadPage(url){
    $('body').append('<div id="progress">загрузка</div>');
    if(url==undefined){
        $('#container').load('index.php #header ul', hijackLinks);
    }
    else{
        $('#container').load(url + ' #content ', hijackLinks);
    }
}
function hijackLinks(){
    $('#container a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        loadPage(e.target.href);
    });
    var title=$('h2').html() || 'Привет';
    $('h1').html(title);
    $('h2').remove();
    $('#progress').remove();
}
```

Comment: А как он должен работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая часть работает (в firefox по крайней мере), по поводу меню:

> не вызывайте обработчики событий в разметке, особенно с jQuery

http://jsbin.com/jemuloqesusi/1/edit,

а вторая не будет работать на jsbin (index.php - 404), попробуйте на plnkr сделать, там можно свои файлы добавлять.

**Обновление**

Сафари тоже на blink - в хроме работает, должно работать и в сафари. Смотрите в консоль, если не работает. И это, у вас там loading кучу раз грузится...

Comment: Дело в том, что я орентируюсь на браузер safari, так как он больше всех подходит под стандарты айфона (по крайне мере так написано), а в этом браузере, когда я прохожу по ссылке, загружается контент, а шапки и заголовков не видно.